# Is there any reason EnumMap and EnumSet are not Navigable

Tags: java, collections, enums

Enum is Comparable which means you can have

```
NavigableSet<AccessMode> modes = new TreeSet<>();
NavigableMap<AccessMode, Object> modeMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

These have O(ln N) access times.

The Enum collections have O(1) access times, but are not Navigable

```
NavigableSet<AccessMode> modes = EnumSet.noneOf(AccessMode.class); // doesn't compile
NavigableMap<AccessMode, Object> modeMap = new EnumMap<>(AccessMode.class);  // doesn't compile
```

I was wondering if there was a reason Enum collections were not Navigable (and Sorted). i.e Am I missing something?

Comment: A sidenote: `EnumSet` is an abstract class.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thank you. I have fixed that example.

Comment: Looking at the implementation, enumsets (both regular and jumbo) happen to be sorted by ascending ordinal value of the enum.

Comment: My guess would be that this is because `enum`s are unordered: the order of declaration is there for your `foreach` loop on `values` and whatnot, but since you can supply your own values, that order does not matter for comparing enum values to each other.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `public class Enum<E extends Enum<E>> implements Comparable<E>, Serializable`.

Comment: Their Iterators are always in ascending order of element or key, which just makes the question more curious to me. ;)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That would makes sense but as Enum extends Comparable, it has a natural order.

Comment: My best guess is that navigability was not seen as a major use case for enum sets. There is nothing in the implementation that would prevent navigability.

Comment: The problem if EnumSet were implementing NavigableSet is that people could be tempted to use a complex and slow way of iterating over what is basically a bit vector. It was probably seen as both useless and never good.

Comment: But @dystroy navigability is not about iteration?

Comment: @dystroy Interesting point.  `iterator()` is one of the things it does provide. Having more methods could mean this is used more often but if you want the first() or last() you need to create an Iterator which is less efficient than what the collection could do internally.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik what would bring navigability on an enumset ? And how would you implement in a reasonable and useful way the subset method ? I mean the good way to use enum based class is to use enum, not iterator() or subset(), etc.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think this is the most likely explanation. If you need it there is always a Tree collection.

Comment: @dystroy The same way TreeSet and TreeMap does now.

Comment: Peter, that was exactly my thinking.

Comment: You should see an enumSet or an hashtable as what it is internally, not as how it is accessible. Because the reason those patterns are common to all languages is that they're efficient (fast and light). In my opinion it makes no sense to access them in ways that aren't based on their inherent efficiency. Using subset on an enumset would either convert to a less efficient type or add weight to all instances.

Comment: @dystroy The enum itself doesn't give you the functionality of `subSet`, `tailSet`, etc. You may imaginably need that. But, as was said here, it seems like a use case rare enough that it didn't get support from the Java library.

Comment: @dystroy EnumSet is under neither a bit set as you said. I don't see much overhead in having a start and end value list as String does for a `substring`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it with bounty.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Here you are, but the bounty really isn't necessary :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik What else is 97K for ;) will add bounty in a of couple hours once the timeout is reached.

Comment: What can I say, thank you very much :)

Comment: Wow, a 500k bounty. I guess only someone digging out that specific E-Mail by Josh Bloch can get this bounty. Or me, indicating that there had been such an E-Mail :-)

Comment: Not quite its 500, not 500k. ;)

Comment: Hah, don't know where the `k` came from. My eyes were all $$

Comment: @LukasEder You really have to want to award bounty. First you have wait for two days. Then you can offer bounty. Then you have to wait 24 hours before you can give it. If you want to give a second bounty it ahas to be the same amount and you have to wait a further 24 hours. But I will do it for you as well. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My best guess is that navigability was not seen as a major use case for enum sets. There is nothing in the implementation that would prevent navigability. The rare use cases that combine the need for a set of enum members with navigability are covered by the `TreeSet` and `TreeMap`.

Comment: I sometimes rely on the iteration order of `EnumSet` and `EnumMap` (it’s documented, so I can do that). I’d love to at least declare my variable a `SortedSet` or `SortedMap` to tell the reader that I know the iteration order. I’d myself call this a use case worth considering. Not asking you to defend the decision taken.

Answer (score 41):

Many "obvious" features are missing from the JDK and its various APIs. Why this particular feature was omitted / forgotten? We can only guess. But your question has been a RFE at Sun/Oracle for a long time:

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6278287
- http://www.java.net/node/644910

You could support those RFEs by commenting on them. Note, here's an authoritative answer by Joshua Bloch on the subject:

> I vaguely recall considering it, but I can't recall whether we
> explicitly rejected it with good reason.  We were running very low on
> time when I implemented EnumSet and EnumMap, and it's possible that
> time played a role in our decision

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jsr.166-concurrency/2158

So even *he* had to guess :-)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I have to admit, I posted 3 of the first 4 links found on Google searching for *"enumset navigable"*, the first one being your SO question ;-)

Comment: Turns out our second-guessing was quite accurate. They ideally could have implemented it, but it would have cost more time and be subject to more bugs and complaints. Since they realized the *navigable* use case was covered by other structures and they were adding this one specifically to stop people from using the "OR-ed bit field" idiom, they dropped it without much worry.

Comment: It's a weird comment by J. Bloch since EnumMap/Set were available in 1.5 and Navigable stuff was introduced in 1.6 to accommodate for ConcurrentSkipListMap. Imo, prime reason for not making EnumMap/Set Navigable is the paperwork - i.e. someone had to write test cases and the overall benefit is too little. Side note: one can find the upper bound by binary search, the lower is available with iterator.

Comment: @bestsss The particular [Bug ID](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4155650) that was quoted at the "what's new in Java 6" was raised in 1998 against Java 1.2. At the time of development of `EnumXxx` they were probably quite familiar with the ongoing work at the `NavigableXxx` interfaces and could have easily decided to implement them in `EnumXxx`. Also, if you look at that Bug ID, it will be clear that `NavigableXxx` doesn't have a specific close link to `CSLM`. Agreed on the paperwork---one must keep in perspective the work needed to release any single line of JDK code.

Comment: @Marko, I am confused, the bug clearly cites *implemented in TreeMap and TreeSet and the new ConcurrentSkipList classes,
coming with the integration of JSR166x* The driving force was JSR166 which also provided the CSLM.

Comment: @bestsss Yes, my point is that this was an integration process where as much attention was paid to `SortedXxx` as to the new concurrent classes. It got introduced to cater for all navigability needs, not specifically the CSLM.

Comment: @Marko, look how http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/ treats  *Navigable collections (concurrent sorted maps and sets) that appear in JDK6*, of course the standard TreeMap should be part of the extra goodliness. Yet, I seriously doubt TreeMap would have got the Navigable touch if JSR166 has not happened (the RFE had way too few votes). I can't be sure though as 2004-2006 were quite dark in my personal history and I was not subscribed to jsr166 either.

Comment: @bestsss Navigable collections are definitely part of JSR166. But is navigability specifically related to concurrent structures? To me it seems that navigability is an orthogonal concern that happened to be in Doug Lea's focus together with the concurrent aspect, which one could argue is the main point of JSR166. I would like to know if I'm wrong on this, so please share any details in that direction.

Comment: (I might get kicked for the long discussion and no move to chat - so the last comment), navigation is important in concurrent structures as they cannot be iterated atomically(or unlocked). Perhaps @TomHawtin can chime in, if someone sees him - tip him :D ; alternatively I might try asking in the jsr166's mailing list.

Comment: @bestsss: Be sure to provide an additional answer to this question, should you find out on the JSR-166 mailing list!

Answer (score 2):

*The post doesn't directly answers the question, neither attempts to, it merely conveys why Navigable was introduced*

*Post as I was requested to (and it's too long for a comment)*

> The short answer is that Navigable exists because we didn't have
> anything like upcoming "defenders" -- Sorted didn't describe all the
> common functionality, and there was no way to do so except to
> introduce a new interface. In practice, I'm sure "Sorted" is still
> used much more often than "Navigable" as a declaration type, because
> most people don't need the methods defined in Navigable but not
> Sorted. Plus "Navigable" is just not a very nice name :-)
>
> -Doug

Comment: Jeez. I guess it's time for a new major Java release, throwing away all the old stuff! :-)

Comment: i am stuck w/ java6 and own backports for the time being.

Comment: This quote only explains the aspect that they had new methods common to all sorted collections that they wanted to abstract in an interface. It still doesn't provide any insight into whether the new methods are specifically important for concurrent use, unfortunately.