# Why do EnumSet is not a SortedSet

Tags: java, enums, set

Enum is Comparable but EnumSet is not a SortedSet.

While you can construct

```
NavigableSet<EnumType> set = new TreeSet<EnumType>();
NavigableMap<EnumType, Object> map = new TreeMap<EnumType, Object>();
```

you can't construct

```
NavigableSet<EnumType> set = new EnumSet<EnumType>();
NavigableMap<EnumType, Object> map = new EnumMap<EnumType, Object>();
```

As Enum is Comparable, this implies it has a natural order which you can use in generic sorted collection but not those collection specific to Enums which appears to be inconsistent.

Insert, update and delete on a Tree is O(log n) whereas for an Enum collection its O(1)

EnumSet collections are not aware that enum is Comparable ?

Please provide link to duplicate question as well . If this is a duplicate

Comment: My guess is all the extra work to make it implement NavigableSet: because it is a lot of work.

Comment: I did a little research, and it appears that this has been asked for many years, i.e. why doesn't `EnumSet` implement `SortedSet`.  I don't see a good answer why they didn't.  One answer is that there was a formal request for this in JDK8, but it just wasn't considered a high enough priority.  See http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2011-August/007382.html.

Comment: For your edit, The link is below the question's title. If you still can't find it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521356/is-there-any-reason-enummap-and-enumset-are-not-navigable